# SAFELY removing duplicates from $PATH, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, path

I am a new programmer with less than 7 months' experience. I want to clean up my `$PATH` because it's filled with numerous duplicates.

E.g.

```
echo $PATH
```

Yields this mess

```
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/home/john/.rbenv/shims:/home/john/.rbenv/bin:/home/john/.rbenv/plugins/rubybuild/bin:/home/john/.rbenv/shims:/home/john/.rbenv/bin:/home/john/bin:/home/john/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/john/.rvm/bin
```

After some research, I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command). It says that this command

```
PATH="$(perl -e 'print join(":", grep { not $seen{$_}++ } split(/:/, $ENV{PATH}))')"
```

will safely remove duplicates. Is this true? Is there a better approach? Don't want to break anything.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You can `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | sort` and see the doubles. I do not write `.. | sort -u | tr '\n' ':'` because the order is important. Check and edit by hand.

Comment: Thank you Walter, that is a sensible solution. It does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked for a script but liked my comment. Therefor I post this as an answer.

You can

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | sort
```

and see the doubles.

Do not try

```
# wrong command beneath
# PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ':')
```

because the order is important. Check and edit by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save the path string in a file and try if it works?

If it doesn't, you can just set it back by hand and everything will still be fine.